# Refreshing google access tokens with the refresh tokens

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

How can I refresh the access tokens in google with the refresh token in python ? I have the refresh token, client id and client secret with me

I have tried with the following code for generating the access token (after expiry)

```
 params = {
            "grant_type": "refresh_token",
            "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "refresh_token": refresh_token
          }
authorization_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

r = requests.post(authorization_url, data=params)
print(r.text)

if r.ok:
       return r.json()['access_token']
else:
       return None
```

I got an error in response like this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

But I need to generate the access token.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the Google api python client library?

Comment: @kkr I think that your script is correct. When I got such error, I avoided the issue by retrieving new refresh token again. Although I'm not sure whether your situation is the same with you, for example, how about retrieving new refresh token and trying again?

Answer (score 0):

These are the three top reasons for it not to be working.  I am not a Python dev so cant test your code sorry.

**Send parms as a string**

Check your parms make sure they are sent as a single string separated with **&**.

```
Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

**content type header**

Also i think you need to set the content type header to something like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**Change endpoint**

If that doesnt work

Also try using  `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`  I remember there being some issue with one or the other of them sometimes